# Multi level pie chart ggplot: Label overlap and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have the following dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
                                          1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                                          1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
                                          3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("2013", "2014", "2015"), 
                                        class = "factor"), 
                       Place = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                                         .Label = c("Inside", "Outside"), 
                                         class = "factor"), 
                       Variable = structure(c(6L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
                                              1L, 3L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 
                                              3L, 14L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 
                                              9L, 9L, 15L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 15L, 1L, 13L, 
                                              1L, 13L, 15L), 
                                            .Label = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", 
                                                       "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5", "Y6", "Y7", "Y8"), 
                                            class = "factor"), 
                       Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                           1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                                         .Label = c("Var1", "Var2"), 
                                         class = "factor"), 
                       Percent = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 2.3, 2.7, 
                                   2.9, 3.4, 3.7, 4.5, 4.7, 5.3, 5.7, 6.2, 7.6, 7.9, 10.6, 10.7, 12.5, 
                                   13.3, 14.4, 15.4, 15.8, 16.9, 17.7, 19.6, 20.5, 24.8, 25.3, 30.4, 31, 
                                   36.8, 41.6, 43.9, 43.9, 44.2, 45.4, 51.8, 52.8, 56.1, 57.4, 68.9, 68.9, 
                                   80.4, 80.4, 81.5)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

I would really like to display the data in a a multilevel like this:

[image: Example Pie Chart]

I tried it by doing:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Group, y = Percent, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  facet_grid(Year ~ Place) +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(Percent, "%", Variable)) ,
            position = position_fill(0.9), size = 3)+
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image: Pie Chart Created with overlapping labels]

But because some percentages are very low, the layers overlap. I would like to either place the labels outside like the example if that's possible.

I have looked at the other forum topics, but because my data is structured in a different way I wasn't able to translate that for me. The other problem is, is that this is just an example but my data input is actually dependent on he Shiny input. So fixing specific angles for this example also doesn't work.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: @Z.Lin Thanks for the edits, didn't know it was possible this way yet, much better

Comment: Are you familiar with the `ggrepel` package? `geom_text_repel()` can rearrange the labels to avoid overlapping, though in some cases the neighbouring slices are all very thin, so the resulting labels may be rather far away. Do also note that based on your data, Var1 & Var2 are not aligned (unlike the example chart). Is this expected behaviour?